# Excel - Autogenerate colums by incrementing a number in text

Tags: excel, excel-formula, xlsx

Is there a way to Auto generate the following column values upto 2000 rows in Excel sheet?

I have a .xlsx file and I want to auto generate the following sequence :

```
Ex : TEST0001
     TEST0002 
     TEST0003
     TEST0004
     TEST0005
     TEST0006
     .
     .
     .
     .
     .
     .
     TEST1000
     TEST1001
     TEST1002
     TEST1003
     .
     .
     .
     .
     .
     TEST2000
```

Any cell formula or built-in UI element that does this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply type TEST0001 in first row and drag it down by holding at the bottom-right corner of the cell. Hope I understood your question.

Answer (score 0):

@wicked_angel is correct.
But if it was a more complex pattern that Excel could not handle that way then you can build it in multiple cells as:

```
 A     B     C    D
test   1     15   A
test   2     14   B
test   3     13   C
```

And so on, then in E you write:

```
=A1&"-"$B1","$C1&" "&D1
```

To get

```
test-1,15 A
test-2,14 B
test-3,13 C
```

As the result.

Because each of the columns are easy enough for Excel to understand but the final pattern might be too much.